# Delayed requests in urql exchange

Tags: javascript, graphql, urql

How to make an Exchange (cache-and-network) to return data from cache immediately and then wait second and make network request to update cache (offline)?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, but if you use graph-cache and you make it schema aware, it will be able to return [partially populated results](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/graphcache/schema-awareness/#partial-results) when all non-nullable fields can be resolved. Is this maybe what you need?

Comment: Or do you want something that follows more the "stale while revalidate" pattern in URQL?